# How to pass encoding in Teradatasql?

Tags: python, teradata, teradatasql

I need to connect to a Teradata table which has encoding = "Latin-OA",
using teradatasql in python.

I tried to pass encoding as a parameter but I don't think it is the correct syntax:

```
with teradatasql.connect(host='xx.xx.xx', user='xyz',
                         password='xyz', charset='Latin-OA') as connect:
    query = 'select * from db.table'
    df = pd.read_sql(query, connect)
    print(df)
```

What is the correct syntax to pass encoding here?

Comment: LATIN1_0A is a client-side encoding, not a "table encoding". Proper design would have translated on input to a valid *server* character set. Data within the database is stored as either Teradata server LATIN (a proprietary Latin-1 variant, close but not identical to LATIN1_0A) or server Unicode (essentially UTF16). The `teradatasql` driver supports only UTF8 as the session character set (which is also the "native" Python3 encoding). If you are encountering a problem with query results, please post a specific question about that.

Answer (score 0):

The teradatasql Python driver does not offer a `charset=` connection parameter.

The teradatasql Python driver always uses the UTF8 session character set.